# No sys/bsdtypes.h when trying to compile a Windows project with mingw on Linux, included at winsock2.h

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw

I'm trying to compile a windows program (a rather simple one, it merely shows a window and plays a sine wave) on Linux. To make sure it's not an X-Y problem, I'm trying to do so for my own convenience, as I'm too used to my Linux hotkeys, workflows etc.

Anyway, what I did is I installed `g++-mingw-w64`, grabbed a `w32api.tar.xz` from mingw sourceforge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/w32api/w32api-5.0.2/), unpacked it in my project directory, grabbed `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` as described in this post (https://www.linux.org/threads/how-to-use-windows-h-c.28353/#post-88213), and am trying to compile the project with

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -I w32api/include/ -L w32api/lib/ source/win32_handmade_linux.cpp
```

What I'm getting is:

```
In file included from w32api/include/winsock2.h:62,
                 from w32api/include/_winsock.h:50,
                 from w32api/include/windows.h:85,
                 from source/win32_handmade_linux.cpp:30:
w32api/include/winsock.h:54:10: fatal error: sys/bsdtypes.h: No such file or directory
   54 | #include <sys/bsdtypes.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Googling it doesn't really help; I can't find that file anywhere on my system, including my Windows installation living on another hard drive. I'm confused. I have to say, I'm not experienced at all with cross-platform compiling, so maybe I'm doing something stupid in the first place and am just not aware of it.

Maybe I took wrong steps there? All windows-specific headers I need are

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <xinput.h>
#include <dsound.h>
```

But maybe it's too hard to achieve anyway, and I should abandon that idea and just compile and run the program under a VM, and develop it on Linux?

Comment: if you already installed MinGW-w64 you don't need a separate w32api or sjlj dll, that should already come with MinGW-w64...

Comment: You could try to just use the standalone MinGW-w64 from https://winlibs.com/ or alternatively install MSYS2 from https://www.msys2.org/ and install MinGW-w64 via the `pacman` command.

Comment: Thanks @BrechtSanders. Used your comment as a hint to solve the problem, I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So, as @BrechtSanders told, I don't need a separate w32api or anything like that, if I already had mingw installed.

Essentially what I did is I've located the headers that came with mingw (on my system, that's `/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/`), located the `libgdi32.a` (`/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libgdi32.a`), and changed the compile command to

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -I /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/ win32_handmade_linux.cpp /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libgdi32.a
```

while deleting bogus DLLs and w32api subdirectory. All works! Moreover, after a little tinkering (I had to put `Z:\\usr\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\9.3-win32\\` to path in `system.reg` in my wine config), the resulting executable runs perfectly under wine!

Comment: The only mystery to solve is how to debug the resulting executable, but that's another story...

Comment: Why didn't you just link with `-lgdi32`?

Comment: Fair question. Well, I didn't know I could do that :)

Comment: That's the way to link to libraries. It should know where to find them. In case of custom libraries you need to add `-L` with the custom location.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I'm not experienced with this stuff at all.